# jQuery mason corner stamp

Tags: jquery-masonry

jQuery Masonry is great, however, has anyone been able to get the corner stamp to appear on the top left side of the page? I tried changing to `float: left;` but that didn't seem to work.

Also, when I resize the window, the resize doesn't automatically adjust for corner stamp.

Here's the CSS

```
.corner-stamp {
width: 270px;
height: 300px;
padding: 10px;
float: right;
background: red;
color: white;
-moz-border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
border-radius: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
```

and here's the JS:

```
$.Mason.prototype.resize = function() {
  this._getColumns();
  this._reLayout();
};
$.Mason.prototype._reLayout = function(callback) {
  var $cornerStamp, cornerStampX, freeCols, i;
  freeCols = this.cols;
  if (this.options.cornerStampSelector) {
    $cornerStamp = this.element.find(this.options.cornerStampSelector);
    cornerStampX = $cornerStamp.offset().left - (this.element.offset().left + this.offset.x + parseInt($cornerStamp.css("marginLeft")));
    freeCols = Math.floor(cornerStampX / this.columnWidth);
  }
  i = this.cols;
  this.colYs = [];
  while (i--) {
    this.colYs.push(this.offset.y);
  }
  i = freeCols;
  while (i < this.cols) {
    this.colYs[i] = this.offset.y + $cornerStamp.outerHeight(true);
    i++;
  }
  this.layout(this.$bricks, callback);
};
$container = $("#streams");
$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector: ".stream-item",
    columnWidth: 60,
    isAnimated: false,
    isFitWidth: true,
    cornerStampSelector: '.corner-stamp'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably find the code you need [right here on github](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/131)

Answer (score 0):

For float left, your best bet is the ensure that the "corned stamped" tile is the first tile in your list.

Also, I've been playing with corner stamping and noticed that the setting `isFitWidth: true` interferes with the corner stamping.

If you have found a better way for left corner stamping, please let me know. And if you've found a way to right corner stamp, yet center the tiles on the page, please let me know.

Thanks.